# How to get the key from an unordered_map with the highest value?

Tags: c++, algorithm, unordered-map

I have the following code that looks if a key exists and if so, returns the key and the value:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, int64_t> id_to_last_observation({
        {"apple", 10},
        {"lily", 12},
        {"avocado", 2},
        {"derry", 5},
        {"elephant", 13},
        {"monkey", 33},
        {"pineapple", 555}, 
        {"car", 1},
        {"ireland", 67},
        {"family", 48},
        {"laptop", 4},
        {"ladder", 90}, // element that begins with l that has the highest value
        {"computer", 98},
        {"travel", 99},
        {"orchestra", 65},
        {"party", 16},
        {"cube", 5}, 
        {"roller-coaster", 8},
        {"snake", 0},
        {"map", 11},
        {"umbrella", 51},
        {"lock", 47},
        {"person", 92},
        {"phone", 89},
        {"pen", 81},
    });

    std::unordered_map<std::string, int64_t>::iterator it;

    it = id_to_last_observation.find("ladder");

    if (it != id_to_last_observation.end()){
        std::cout << "Element Found - ";
        std::cout << it ->first<< "::" << it->second<< std::endl;
    }else{
        std::cout << "Element Not Found" << std::endl;
    }return 0;
```

However, I'm doing it manually here. What I want to do is to get the element that begins with whatever letter I want and that has whatever value (highest, lowest, etc) I want. So If I want the element that begins with `l` and that also has the highest value among all elements that begin with `l`, I want to return `ladder`.

Is there a way to do this efficiently without bruteforcing?

Comment: *Is there a way to do this efficiently without bruteforcing?* -- Given that you need all of this extra information, the first thing you should have thought of should have been having an auxiliary data structure that holds this information.

Comment: The second thing is that in a real program, you would probably had not have hardcoded those map entries, instead they would have been generated programmatically in some sort of loop.  If that was the case, then the obvious solution would have been to keep a tally of the entries being added, and update another data structure, probably another map, with the information on the highest value.  You need to be more specific as to how that initial map is actually built.  But even then, a tiny 26 entry map isn't worth trying to figure out a quicker way, IMO.

Comment: It sounds like you actually want a map from the first letter to a sequence of pairs of word and value, sorted on value.

Comment: Perhaps an `unordered_map` is not the best thing to have? Depending on your use case, seems like a trie combined with a heap.

Comment: *"I have to use an unordered_map for the sake of this assignment."* - this is still vague.  Must you ***only*** use an `unordered_map`?  If so, then you do have to do a brute force search.  If you may *also* use a supplementary container, what's best depends on whether the id_to_last_observation entries may be erased; if you just insert new values, an `std::array<decltype(id_to_last_observation::iterator), 26>` can be updated whenever inserting a word with a higher value.  To support erases, consider an array of `priority_queue`s or sets, sorting on the numeric values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no built-in method that does this. That's what "unordered" means. By definition: the values in an unordered map are not stored in any specific order.

Even for a regular, ordered `std::map`: the only thing that its available methods will give you, if used wisely, is the range of the keys, but you will still need to search through them all.

Note that either in an `unordered_map` or a `map`, the values are modifiable, and you can modify the value stored under any key at any time you wish, and the map will not care at all. So, given that, how do you expect your map to even have any way of doing that?

Comment: I didn't ask if there is a built-in method to do this. I'm asking if there is an efficient way of finding the element without brute-forcing. I have to use an unordered_map for the sake of this assignment. I can brute force this but I would rather not if there is a way to reduce worst-case.

Comment: The last sentence in the first paragraph answers that, directly: there isn't. Unordered means that: unordered. There is no specific order of keys in the unordered map. If there is no specific order of keys in an unordered map then, by definition, brute force is the only thing that can be done.